# RestClient::RequestTimeout: Request Timeout, when running rspec locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I recently changed laptops and now Rspec doesn't seem to run normally locally. 
When I run a simple test:

```
describe 'price' do
    let(:product) { create(:product) }
    let(:product_item) { create(:product_item, product_id: product.id) }
    it "is half of the retail price if it has never been rented" do
      product.update_attributes(sale_price_new: [200_000, 190_000])
      product_item.reload

      expect(product_item.price(2.days.from_now, "EUR")).to eq(100_000)
    end
```

I get

```
Failures:

  1) ProductItem price is half of the retail price if it has never been rented
     Failure/Error: let(:product) { create(:product) }

     RestClient::RequestTimeout:
       Request Timeout
     # ./spec/models/product_item_spec.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/product_item_spec.rb:160:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # IO::EAGAINWaitReadable:
     #   Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block
     #   ./spec/models/product_item_spec.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But when I run it on the server, or in the previous laptop, everything works fine. 
Anyone knows what I'm missing?
Thank you so much!